# How to add filter and pagination with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create an API that will return all customers record from the database. But this provides pagination and filtering.,

The filtering feature is an optional query parameter. So would not necessary included it inside query parameter.

But i am facing an issues in doing that.

Here is my index methods from `CustomerController` file:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Get how many item per page
        $itemPerPage = $request->query('per_page');

        // SQL Query 
        $customers = Customer::all();

        // Filter data
        if (!empty($request->name)) {
            $customers = $customers->where('name', '=', $request->name);
        }

        // Return the result as JSON
        return new CustomerCollection($customers->paginate($itemPerPage));
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

Or have any better approach to combine optional filtering feature with pagination?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked for a *Laravel pagination* or *Laravel API pagination* tutorials? Have a look at the official documentation and how they use it: [Laravel 9.x: pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination). This exists for older versions as well.

Comment: Hi @PeterKrebs that for your response. I had read the official documentation. But i found that I can't join the paginate before or after where clause. But in my scenario, I need the filtering part to be optional so i cannot add where clause after Customer::

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for your solution. I just know there is a query() clause after reading your reply. Really appreciated! Your solution is worked perfectly from my side. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is this line:

```
$customers = Customer::all();
```

The `all()` method immediately returns all `customers` records as a `Collection`, which does not have a `->paginate()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods.

To optionally chain, use the `->query()` method, or a `->when()` clause:

Using `::query()` instead of `::all()`:

```php
$itemPerPage = $request->query('per_page');

// SQL Query 
$customers = Customer::query();

// Filter data
if (!empty($request->name)) {
    $customers = $customers->where('name', '=', $request->name);
}

// Return the result as JSON
return new CustomerCollection($customers->paginate($itemPerPage));
```

Using a `->when()` clause:

```
$itemPerPage = $request->query('per_page');

$customers = Customer::when(!empty($request->name), function ($query) use ($request) {
  $query->where('name', '=', $request->name);
});

return new CustomerCollection($customers->paginate($itemPerPage));
```